# Parsing fields in django-import-export before importing

Tags: python, django, django-models, geodjango, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export package to expect a csv file containing a location's name and its longitude and latitude.

I want to parse the longitude and latitude field from the csv to convert them into `django.contrib.gis.geos.Point` object so that I can input it to my `Location` model's `geom` field.

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    geom = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# admin.py
from .models import Location
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class LocationResource(resources.ModelResource):
    geom = Field()
    latitude = Field()
    longitude = Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id','name', 'latitude', 'longitude')
        exclude = ('geom')
        export_order = ('id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude')

    def dehydrate_geom(self, data):
        return Point(data.longitude, data.longitude)

class LocationAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = LocationResource

admin.site.register(Location, LocationAdmin)
```

This is how far I got but to no success.
Must have:

```
Location(name='name', geom=Point(longitude, latitude))
```

CSV file: locations.csv

```
id,name,longitude,latitude
1,Naga,120.18,18.20
```

**UPDATE 1**
Tried using `hydrate_<field_name>` but with no success.

```
class ProjectActivityResource(resources.ModelResource):
    latitude = Field(attribute='latitude', column_name='latitude')
    longitude = Field(attribute='longitude', column_name='longitude')

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectActivity
        fields = ('id', 'project_site', 'name', 'latitude',
                        'longitude', 'date_updated')
        exclude = ('geom')
        export_order = ('id', 'project_site', 'name', 'latitude',
                        'longitude', 'date_updated')

    def hydrate_geom(self, project_activity):
        print(project_activity)
        return Point(float(project_activity.longitude), float(project_activity.longitude))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was resolved when I used `before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run)`

The function can modify the object before passing it to the model.

```
class ProjectActivityResource(resources.ModelResource):
    latitude = Field(attribute='latitude', column_name='latitude')
    longitude = Field(attribute='longitude', column_name='longitude')

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectActivity
        fields = ('id', 'project_site', 'name', 'latitude',
                        'longitude', 'date_updated')
        exclude = ('geom')
        export_order = ('id', 'project_site', 'name', 'latitude',
                        'longitude', 'date_updated')

    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        instance.geom = Point(float(instance.longitude), float(instance.latitude))
        return instance
```

Comment: Excellent this answer helped me a lot. Cheers

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: from import_export.fields import Field

Comment: from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem, similar to @Nikko. I had a really hard time doing what I wanted, and Nikko pieces of code helped. I'm not completely satisfied with what I've done but **it works** and maybe it can help some people. **It's dirty** so if someone wants to explain me what would be the right way, I'm all ears.

This code allows you to import AND export (using django-import-export), from the admin interface, a class containing a PointField (from django-geojson) by storing only the latitude and the longitude in the output file (not the all geojson file).

admin.py :

```
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
import json

from django.db import models
from djgeojson.fields import PointField

class SleepSpotResource(resources.ModelResource):
    latitude = Field(attribute='latitude', column_name='latitude')
    longitude = Field(attribute='longitude', column_name='longitude')

    class Meta:
        model = SleepSpot
        fields = ('id','album','title','start_date','end_date','latitude','longitude' )
        exclude = ('geom')
        export_order = ('id','album','title','start_date','end_date','latitude','longitude' )

    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        longitude = float(getattr(instance, 'longitude'))
        latitude = float(getattr(instance, 'latitude'))

        instance.geom = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [longitude, latitude]}
        return instance

    def dehydrate_longitude(self, sleepspot):
        try:
            geomjson = sleepspot.geom
            if type(geomjson) is str:
                geomjson = json.loads(geomjson.replace("\'", "\""))
            return geomjson['coordinates'][0]
        except:
            pass

    def dehydrate_latitude(self, sleepspot):
        try:
            geomjson = sleepspot.geom
            if type(geomjson) is str:
                geomjson = json.loads(geomjson.replace("\'", "\""))
            return geomjson['coordinates'][1]
        except:
            pass

@admin.register(SleepSpot)
class SleepSpotModelAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'album')
    resource_class = SleepSpotResource
```

Comment: Glad to know it helped you. I also have an answer for your question. I hope it also helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Friedrich, a PointField has a method *coords*. I did not test this though.

I would do this:

```
def dehydrate_longitude(self, sleepspot):
    return sleepspot.geom.coords[0]

def dehydrate_longitude(self, sleepspot):
    return sleepspot.geom.coords[1]
```

as long as it is saved as PointField:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
instance.geom = Point(float(instance.longitude), float(instance.latitude))
```

instead of a JSON

`instance.geom = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [longitude, latitude]}`